# How to regex 0 or digit in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I'm tryin to capture the follwoing from the below lines in my file:

```
1.39223 0.303787
71.9792 0
```

Input file (example):

```
XLOC_000559 XLOC_000559 -   S3603:13352-18211   con exp OK  1.39223 0.303787    -2.19627    -1.93877    0.0001  0.0140909   yes
XLOC_001511 XLOC_001511 -   S7778:1319-1421 con exp OK  71.9792 0   -inf    -nan    0.00035 0.0365407   yes
```

I've tried the regex:

```
my ($con_val, $expt_val) = ($1, $2) if ($_ =~ /OK\t(\d+\.\d+)\t(\d+\.\d+)/);
```

But its not working on 0 values...

Can anyone help please?

Comment: If you have received a satisfactory solution then you should mark it as accepted. If not, then please describe what additional problems you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is almost certainly no need to make sure your numbers contain a maximum of one decimal point, and the easiest way to solve this is to use a *character class* `[\d.]` that matches any digit or a dot.

Note that a regex will be applied to `$_` unless you say otherwise, so there is no need to write `$_ =~`.

This short program should help you.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
  next unless /OK\s+([\d.]+)\s+([\d.]+)/;
  my ($con_val, $expt_val) = ($1, $2);
  print "$con_val, $expt_val\n";
}

__DATA__
XLOC_000559 XLOC_000559 -   S3603:13352-18211   con exp OK  1.39223 0.303787    -2.19627    -1.93877    0.0001  0.0140909   yes
XLOC_001511 XLOC_001511 -   S7778:1319-1421 con exp OK  71.9792 0   -inf    -nan    0.00035 0.0365407   yes
```

**output**

```
1.39223, 0.303787
71.9792, 0
```

Comment: it'll match `11.22.33` and utf digits outside `[0-9]` which is by some considered as ultimate mistake/evil. :o

Comment: @mpapec: If you really want to *verify* your data as well as extracting the correct data fields then it is best to do that separately. Just because regexes *can* do everything at once it doesn't mean you *should* use them that way. You wouldn't consider doing it with any other language.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make the `\.\d+` optional by wrapping it in parentheses with a `?`:

```
/OK\t(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\t(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)/
```

The `?:` after the open-paren prevents the regex engine from creating a grouping in the match result.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Regexp::Common;
my ($con_val, $expt_val) = /OK\s+ ($RE{num}{real}) \s+ ($RE{num}{real})/x;
```

or

```
perl -anE 'say "@F[7,8]"' file
```

Comment: whats the `num` and `real` doing?

Comment: @user2729360 these are regex definitions for matching common patterns like decimal numbers above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the second value (that you want to capture as '$expt_val') is always followed by a tab character, this should work:

```
my ($con_val, $expt_val) = ($1, $2) if ($row =~ /OK\t(\d+\.\d+)\t(.+)\t/);
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use the or operator `|` to specify either:

- One or more digits `(\d+)` followed by a literal `.` `(\.)` followed by one or more digits `(\d+)`

OR

- A literal `0`

Try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict; 
use Data::Dumper;

my @array =('XLOC_000559    XLOC_000559 -   S3603:13352-18211   con exp OK  1.39223 0.303787    -2.19627    -1.93877    0.0001  0.0140909   yes',
    'XLOC_001511    XLOC_001511 -   S7778:1319-1421 con exp OK  71.9792 0   -inf    -nan    0.00035 0.0365407   yes');

foreach (@array){
    my ($con_val, $expt_val) = ($1, $2) if ($_ =~ /OK\t(\d+\.\d+|0)\t(\d+\.\d+|0)/); 
    print "$con_val\t$expt_val\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
1.39223 0.303787
71.9792 0
```

Or better yet, assuming your values are separated by a `\t`, I'd go for this:

```
my (@con_val, @expt_val);
foreach (@array){
    my @split = split(/\t/);
    push @con_val, $split[7];
    push @expt_val, $split[8];
}

print Dumper \@expt_val;
print Dumper \@con_val;
```

Outputs:

```
$VAR1 = [
          '0.303787',
          '0'
        ];
$VAR1 = [
          '1.39223',
          '71.9792'
        ];
```

Comment: In the second they are beackward?

Comment: Dont worry : my mistake!

Comment: This assumes that any integer other than zero will have a decimal point and trailing zeroes. I think it's much more likely that, for example, three will appear as just `3` rather than `3.000000`.